# Downloading only .owl files via wget spanning two sites in two link steps

Tags: wget

I'm trying to figure out how to download all the files ending with **.owl** linked to from http://www.ontobee.org/ via sub-pages

- http://www.ontobee.org/ontology/AEO
- http://www.ontobee.org/ontology/AERO
  ...

For instance, for the AEO ontology case the file

http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/aeo.owl

is the only one I'm interested in.

My current try is

`wget -r -l 2 -H -D http://www.ontobee.org,http://purl.obolibrary.org --accept "*.owl" http://www.ontobee.org/`

but that only downloads a single file. What's wrong?